# Why can´t Geowebcache communicate with geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I have installed geoserver 2.5 with integrated GWC on a windows server 2008 R2 in tomcat6. I am not able to create map caches with GWC. GWC gives me "404: cannot communicate with server. I have a reverse proxy set up and a url rewrite in IIS to provide internet access. What do I have to do to establish communication again between Geoserver and GWC?

Comment: it should just work in that configuration - can you give more details of how you configured GWC? What the log file says (when you've turned up logging)

Comment: Due to the length of the logs, I don´t think I can post it here....Ill have a look and see if there is anything significant that stands out

Comment: Stack trace is here http://pastebin.com/PRTir8f7

Comment: I haven´t configured Geowebcache at all really. I simply tried to add 2 new grids for EPSG:25832 and EPSG:31467. I enabled Direct wms integration just to see if this did anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what stands out to me is

> org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException No such style THW

I suspect that you have left out a style or have misspelled it (or it might be hiding in a workspace).

Comment: It is true that this style is in the workspace "geoportal"...Why is it "hiding" in a workspace...the normal wms works fine- How do I "unhide" it?

Comment: GWC doesn't understand about your workspaces - there are some issues with the way workspaces interact with styles. Either move the style out of the workspace or add the workspace to the GeoServer URL you configure to GWC (e.g. http://..../geoserver/workspace/wms)

Comment: Exactly right!...once I took the styles out of the workspace it worked fine..Thanks for your help

Comment: GeoServer 2.6 will allow you to pass the workspace through using a a parameter filter, allowing styles in workpaces to be used. https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/pull/622